# Error inflating Class Fragment exception (FC)

Tags: android, eclipse

Just so you guys are aware- I have limited prorgrmming experience- At this level, anyways.  I have been struggling the last few days with this error as I don't know exactly what the logcat is trying to say.  Could you guys help me out?  (Yes, a large portion of this code was copied from the AOSP repo. I am trying to adapt it to my needs.)

Anything you guys can offer will be greatly appreciated

**Logcat:**

```
03-31 12:49:07.814: D/AndroidRuntime(8809): Shutting down VM
03-31 12:49:07.834: W/dalvikvm(8809): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a4f1f8)
03-31 12:49:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(8809): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-31 12:49:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(8809): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.senseimods.wallpapers.heavymetals/com.senseimods.wallpapers.heavymetals.HeavyMetalsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #4: Error inflating class fragment
03-31 12:49:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(8809):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
03-31 12:49:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(8809):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
03-31 12:49:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(8809):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
03-31 12:49:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(8809):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
03-31 12:49:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(8809):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-31 12:49:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(8809):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-31 12:49:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(8809):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
03-31 12:49:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(8809):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-31 12:49:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(8809):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-31 12:49:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(8809):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
03-31 12:49:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(8809):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
03-31 12:49:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(8809):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-31 12:49:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(8809): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #4: Error inflating class fragment
03-31 12:49:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(8809):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
03-31 12:49:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(8809):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
03-31 12:49:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(8809):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
03-31 12:49:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(8809):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
03-31 12:49:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(8809):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
03-31 12:49:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(8809):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
03-31 12:49:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(8809):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
03-31 12:49:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(8809):     at com.senseimods.wallpapers.heavymetals.HeavyMetalsActivity.onCreate(HeavyMetalsActivity.java:15)
03-31 12:49:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(8809):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
03-31 12:49:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(8809):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
03-31 12:49:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(8809):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
03-31 12:49:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(8809):     ... 11 more
03-31 12:49:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(8809): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.senseimods.heavymetals.WallpaperChooserDialogFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
03-31 12:49:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(8809):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:581)
03-31 12:49:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(8809):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:549)
03-31 12:49:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(8809):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4235)
03-31 12:49:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(8809):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:673)
03-31 12:49:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(8809):     ... 21 more
03-31 12:49:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(8809): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.senseimods.heavymetals.WallpaperChooserDialogFragment
03-31 12:49:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(8809):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
03-31 12:49:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(8809):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
03-31 12:49:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(8809):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
03-31 12:49:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(8809):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:571)
03-31 12:49:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(8809):     ... 24 more
03-31 12:54:07.937: I/Process(8809): Sending signal. PID: 8809 SIG: 9
```

**Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.senseimods.wallpapers.heavymetals"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/application_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".HeavyMetalsActivity"
            android:label="@string/application_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <activity
                android:name=".WallpaperChooserDialogFragment"
                android:label="@string/application_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Expander:**

```
package com.senseimods.wallpapers.heavymetals;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class HeavyMetalsActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "WallpaperChooser";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.wallpaper_chooser_base);
        Fragment fragmentView = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.wallpaper_chooser_fragment);
        // TODO: The following code is currently not exercised. Leaving it here
        // in case it
        // needs to be revived again.
        if (fragmentView == null) {
            /*
             * When the screen is XLarge, the fragment is not included in the
             * layout, so show it as a dialog
             */
            DialogFragment fragment = WallpaperChooserDialogFragment
                    .newInstance();
            fragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
        }
    }
}
```

**Launch Activity:**

```
private static final String TAG = "WallpaperChooserDialogFragment";
    private static final String EMBEDDED_KEY = "com.senseimods.wallpapers."
            + "WallpaperChooserDialogFragment.EMBEDDED_KEY";

    private boolean mEmbedded;
    private Bitmap mBitmap = null;

    private ArrayList<Integer> mThumbs;
    private ArrayList<Integer> mImages;
    private WallpaperLoader mLoader;
    private WallpaperDrawable mWallpaperDrawable = new WallpaperDrawable();

    public static WallpaperChooserDialogFragment newInstance() {
        WallpaperChooserDialogFragment fragment = new WallpaperChooserDialogFragment();
        fragment.setCancelable(true);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null
                && savedInstanceState.containsKey(EMBEDDED_KEY)) {
            mEmbedded = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(EMBEDDED_KEY);
        } else {
            mEmbedded = isInLayout();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putBoolean(EMBEDDED_KEY, mEmbedded);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (mLoader != null
                && mLoader.getStatus() != WallpaperLoader.Status.FINISHED) {
            mLoader.cancel(true);
            mLoader = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        super.onDismiss(dialog);
        /*
         * On orientation changes, the dialog is effectively "dismissed" so this
         * is called when the activity is no longer associated with this dying
         * dialog fragment. We should just safely ignore this case by checking
         * if getActivity() returns null
         */
        Activity activity = getActivity();
        if (activity != null) {
            activity.finish();
        }
    }

    /*
     * This will only be called when in XLarge mode, since this Fragment is
     * invoked like a dialog in that mode
     */
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        findWallpapers();

        // TODO: The following code is not exercised right now and may be
        // removed
        // if the dialog version is not needed.
        /*
         * final View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(
         * R.layout.wallpaper_chooser, null, false);
         * 
         * GridView gridView = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.gallery);
         * gridView.setOnItemClickListener(this); gridView.setAdapter(new
         * ImageAdapter(getActivity()));
         * 
         * final int viewInset =
         * getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.alert_dialog_content_inset
         * );
         * 
         * FrameLayout wallPaperList = (FrameLayout)
         * v.findViewById(R.id.wallpaper_list); AlertDialog.Builder builder =
         * new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
         * builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.wallpaper_cancel, null);
         * builder.setTitle(R.string.wallpaper_dialog_title);
         * builder.setView(wallPaperList, viewInset, viewInset, viewInset,
         * viewInset); return builder.create();
         */
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        findWallpapers();

        /*
         * If this fragment is embedded in the layout of this activity, then we
         * should generate a view to display. Otherwise, a dialog will be
         * created in onCreateDialog()
         */
        if (mEmbedded) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.wallpaper_chooser, container,
                    false);
            view.setBackgroundDrawable(mWallpaperDrawable);

            final Gallery gallery = (Gallery) view.findViewById(R.id.gallery);
            gallery.setCallbackDuringFling(false);
            gallery.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
            gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity()));

            View setButton = view.findViewById(R.id.set);
            setButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    selectWallpaper(gallery.getSelectedItemPosition());
                }
            });
            return view;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void selectWallpaper(int position) {
        try {
            WallpaperManager wpm = (WallpaperManager) getActivity()
                    .getSystemService(Context.WALLPAPER_SERVICE);
            wpm.setResource(mImages.get(position));
            Activity activity = getActivity();
            activity.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
            activity.finish();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to set wallpaper: " + e);
        }
    }

    // Click handler for the Dialog's GridView
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        selectWallpaper(position);
    }

    // Selection handler for the embedded Gallery view
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        if (mLoader != null
                && mLoader.getStatus() != WallpaperLoader.Status.FINISHED) {
            mLoader.cancel();
        }
        mLoader = (WallpaperLoader) new WallpaperLoader().execute(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }

    private void findWallpapers() {
        mThumbs = new ArrayList<Integer>(24);
        mImages = new ArrayList<Integer>(24);

        final Resources resources = getResources();
        // Context.getPackageName() may return the "original" package name,
        // com.cyanogenmod.trebuchet; Resources needs the real package name,
        // com.cyanogenmod.trebuchet. So we ask Resources for what it thinks the
        // package name should be.
        final String packageName = resources
                .getResourcePackageName(R.array.wallpapers);

        addWallpapers(resources, packageName, R.array.wallpapers);
        addWallpapers(resources, packageName, R.array.extra_wallpapers);
    }

    private void addWallpapers(Resources resources, String packageName, int list) {
        final String[] extras = resources.getStringArray(list);
        for (String extra : extras) {
            int res = resources.getIdentifier(extra, "drawable", packageName);
            if (res != 0) {
                final int thumbRes = resources.getIdentifier(extra + "_small",
                        "drawable", packageName);

                if (thumbRes != 0) {
                    mThumbs.add(thumbRes);
                    mImages.add(res);
                    // Log.d(TAG, "add: [" + packageName + "]: " + extra + " ("
                    // + res + ")");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter,
            SpinnerAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

        ImageAdapter(Activity activity) {
            mLayoutInflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return mThumbs.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view;

            if (convertView == null) {
                view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.wallpaper_item, parent,
                        false);
            } else {
                view = convertView;
            }

            ImageView image = (ImageView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.wallpaper_image);

            int thumbRes = mThumbs.get(position);
            image.setImageResource(thumbRes);
            Drawable thumbDrawable = image.getDrawable();
            if (thumbDrawable != null) {
                thumbDrawable.setDither(true);
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error decoding thumbnail resId=" + thumbRes
                        + " for wallpaper #" + position);
            }

            return view;
        }
    }

    class WallpaperLoader extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap> {
        BitmapFactory.Options mOptions;

        WallpaperLoader() {
            mOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            mOptions.inDither = false;
            mOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            if (isCancelled())
                return null;
            try {
                return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        mImages.get(params[0]), mOptions);
            } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap b) {
            if (b == null)
                return;

            if (!isCancelled() && !mOptions.mCancel) {
                // Help the GC
                if (mBitmap != null) {
                    mBitmap.recycle();
                }

                View v = getView();
                if (v != null) {
                    mBitmap = b;
                    mWallpaperDrawable.setBitmap(b);
                    v.postInvalidate();
                } else {
                    mBitmap = null;
                    mWallpaperDrawable.setBitmap(null);
                }
                mLoader = null;
            } else {
                b.recycle();
            }
        }

        void cancel() {
            mOptions.requestCancelDecode();
            super.cancel(true);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Custom drawable that centers the bitmap fed to it.
     */
    static class WallpaperDrawable extends Drawable {

        Bitmap mBitmap;
        int mIntrinsicWidth;
        int mIntrinsicHeight;

        /* package */void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
            mBitmap = bitmap;
            if (mBitmap == null)
                return;
            mIntrinsicWidth = mBitmap.getWidth();
            mIntrinsicHeight = mBitmap.getHeight();
        }

        @Override
        public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
            if (mBitmap == null)
                return;
            int width = canvas.getWidth();
            int height = canvas.getHeight();
            int x = (width - mIntrinsicWidth) / 2;
            int y = (height - mIntrinsicHeight) / 2;
            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, x, y, null);
        }

        @Override
        public int getOpacity() {
            return android.graphics.PixelFormat.OPAQUE;
        }

        @Override
        public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
            // Ignore
        }

        @Override
        public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
            // Ignore
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The key line is:

```
Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.senseimods.heavymetals.WallpaperChooserDialogFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
```

You are violating one of those three rules:

- The class must exist
- The class must be public
- The class must have a public empty constructor

It is also possible you are violating a fourth rule:

- Attempting to pretend that something that does not extend `Fragment` is a `Fragment`

I say that because you have an `<activity>` element in your manifest declaring that `WallpaperChooserDialogFragment` is an activity, not a fragment.

If `WallpaperChooserDialogFragment` is a `Fragment`, in addition to fixing the bug that is causing your crash (see bulleted list above), you need to remove that `<activity>` element, as it is wrong.

If `WallpaperChooserDialogFragment` is not a `Fragment`, but rather is an activity, you may wish to rename the class to not have `Fragment` in it, and you cannot try casting it to be a `DialogFragment` or otherwise treat it as a fragment.

Comment: I went ahead and removed the activity tag.  Thanks for pointing that out.  I can confirm that the class DOES exist, and the class IS public.  As for the other two, I am not sure how to determine if those are being violated or not. Could you help me determine that?

Comment: @user1291949: I do not see a constructor in your code above, but you do not have a complete code listing -- it is missing some of the top lines, such as the class declaration. Edit your question and add in the missing lines, then comment back on here so I know you made the change (SO won't automatically ping me when you edit your question).

Comment: I think this may be broken beyond repair.  Basically what I want to do is have a list of images displayed (either in a galleryview or a gridview) and allow the user to choose one to set as their wallpaper. So I took what I thought I needed from the AOSP home application.  I think this wasw the wrong approach. Can you suggest a better solution?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @user1291949: "So I took what I thought I needed from the AOSP home application" -- that is akin to swatting a fly with a piano. You are likely to miss the fly, and it is bad for the piano. "Can you suggest a better solution?" -- search Google for `android "open source" wallpaper (chooser OR changer)` and pick something, like http://code.google.com/p/walli-e/, that is more focused on your specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

I too felt same inflateException,can not instataniate error,
but in my case it was due to android package renaming.
If you also renamed the package name and then facing this problem,then there are chances that R.java and some entries are still older, simply F2 on package name & renaming it is not the solution.
you search with ctrl+f for the package name & rename it correctly everywher....

Answer (score 0):

The exception `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line: #... Error inflating class fragment` might happen if you manipulate with `getActivity()` inside your fragment before `onActivityCreated()` get called. In such case you receive a wrong activity reference and can't rely on that.

For instance the next pattern is wrong:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout..., container, false);

    Button button = getActivity().findViewById(R.id...);
    button.setOnClickListener(...); - another problem: button is null

    return view;
}
```